# Why we need SATB algorithm in concurrent GC tracing?

Tags: garbage-collection

Say in concurrent GC, at the beginning of tracing, object A is in
root set. And object A refers to B and C. B and C are on
heap. And during tracing, mutator changes A's reference to C. So
C is dead. And the [SATB algorithm](https://books.google.com/books?id=jZG_DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA295&lpg=PA295&dq=With+a+STW+tracing+GC,+all+the+objects+reachable&source=bl&ots=KvmXYp3XX4&sig=D3weDp6cue96ZpBTEZBob3myQa8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL-eDN6c3UAhXIqo8KHTghDroQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=With%20a%20STW%20tracing%20GC%2C%20all%20the%20objects%20reachable&f=false) says C will be saved in remember
set by writer barrier. But if we did not save C in remember set,
there will be 2 cases could happen:

1. the mutator's changing to C happens before tracing thread
   reaching to C. Then when tracing thread will not reach to C, C is
   already dead. In this round of tracing, the live set includes only B.
2. the mutator's changing to C happens after tracing thread
   reaching to C (but before next round of tracing). Then
   tracing thread is able to reach C. In this round of tracing,
   the live set includes B and C. C will be collected in next round
   of tracing.

So in above 2 cases, we could always get the correct set B in first round of tracing or next round of tracing without SATB.

So my question is: in above case, SATB is not necessary at all to
keep concurrent GC correct. Why we bother to do save the snapshot
in writer barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is not really interesting for the discussion of concurrent collectors. C is dead, whether the collector notices its unreachability during the current or the next cycle makes little difference since a GC does not guarantee that memory gets freed immediately anyway.

The interesting cases are about live objects, since those are the ones don't want to be freed by accident. This can easily happen when a mutator takes an object (existing or newly created) that has not been marked yet and puts it in a field of a marked-reachable object. Since the holding object is already marked the collector it will not visit the other object and thus the write barrier will have to assist some way. SATB is one of those ways.

Comment: thanks for your answer!Could you show some example, in which SATB could help?

Comment: Thanks! The case helps a lot!